# Javascript swipe to close functionality not working with my CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css

> You may have to use the Chrome's inspect tool in mobile view to test as that will trigger the touch events correctly.

I have a drawer which can be opened and closed which plays open and close animations using keyframes. This part alone works fine. I also have "swipe to close" logic set up where the drawer will follow your finger as you swipe on it. If you swipe far enough it will then trigger a close. This part alone also works fine.

My issue is with combining the 2 features. Currently, when you swipe to close the drawer, instead of the animation playing from the current position the drawer is at to a closed position, it instead resets to being fully open before starting the closing animation. This is obviously not desirable. How can I fix this?

I also tried to solve this using transitions instead of animations, but even though the "swipe-to-close" functionality works better with transition, I am not able to get the transitions play correctly when opening and closing the drawer.

```js
const open = document.querySelector(".open");
const close = document.querySelector(".close");
const drawer = document.querySelector(".drawer");

open.addEventListener("click", () => {
  drawer.setAttribute("data-open", "");
  drawer.setAttribute("data-opening", "");
  setTimeout(() => {
    drawer.removeAttribute("data-opening");
  }, 1000);
});

close.addEventListener("click", () => {
  drawer.setAttribute("data-closing", "");
  setTimeout(() => {
    drawer.removeAttribute("data-closing");
    drawer.removeAttribute("data-open");
  }, 1000);
});



let xTouchStart;
let yTouchStart;
const slideThreshold = 10;
const closeThreshold = 100;
        
const handleTouchMove = (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    if (touch.screenX - xTouchStart > slideThreshold) {
        drawer.style.transition = "transform 0s";
        drawer.style.transform = `translateX(${touch.screenX - xTouchStart - slideThreshold}px)`;
    }
}

const handleTouchEnd = (e) => {
    drawer.style.transition = "";
    drawer.style.transform = "";
    const touch = e.changedTouches[0];
    if (touch.screenX - xTouchStart > closeThreshold) {
        close.click();
    }
    drawer.removeEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
    drawer.removeEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
    drawer.removeEventListener("touchcancel", handleTouchEnd);
};

drawer.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
    const touch = e.touches[0];
    xTouchStart = touch.screenX;
    yTouchStart = touch.screenY;
    drawer.addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
    drawer.addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
    drawer.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleTouchEnd);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}
.drawer {
  pointer-events: all;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20rem;
  background: skyblue;
}
.drawer[data-open] {
  display: block;
}
.drawer[data-opening] {
  animation: open 1000ms forwards;
}
.drawer[data-closing] {
  animation: close 1000ms forwards;
}

@keyframes open {
    0% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
}

@keyframes close {
    100% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="drawer">
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="open">open</button>
```

Comment: If you're using the javascript before the end of the head tag, wrap it around windows.onload = () => {

}

Comment: @Richie I am not?

Comment: it works here. Where exactly have you placed the code?